# MySQL select Distinct records in 1 table and count each group based on values in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1:

```
| user           | bid |
---------------------------
|    may    |      0.06      |
|    dee    |      0.05      |
|    jay    |      0.04      |
|    mac    |      0.03      |
|    dee    |      0.02      |
|    mac    |      0.01      |
```

Table 2:

```
| user          | ratio|
---------------------------
|    dee    |      .25      |
|    jay    |      .45      |
|    mac    |      .85      |
|    fil    |      .75      |
|    may    |      .95      |
```

I want to count how many distinct users from table 1 fall within certain ranges (0-.99) based on their ration in table 2.

Output:

```
| Ratio_Group     | Count|
---------------------------
|    0.00-0.25 |      1     |
|    0.25-0.50 |      1     |
|    0.50-0.75 |      0     |
|    0.75-0.99 |      2     |
```

Is there 1 query per ratio grouping I can use to count the distinct users in table 1 based on what grouping they fall into in table 2? I was using a combination of a IF and COUNT statement, but each row in table 1 was evaluated and counted instead of just the DISTINCT users and therefore I got an inflated result.

Ex:

```
 COUNT((IF table1.user <0.25,1,0))
 COUNT((IF table1.user BETWEEN 0.25 AND 0.50,1,0))
 etc...
```

Each of the 4 queries will be used in a stored proc so I need 1 query per ratio grouping so I may assign the result of each group to a variable in the stored proc.

Comment: Do you have a `user_id` or is `user` the PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: the 'user' is the primary key in table 2. In table 1 the primary key is the bid.

Comment: Correction: In table 1 both 'bid" an a unique ID in conjunction are the primary keys. Table 1 will have multiple examples like the one above. I did not enter the unique ID for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM` with a combination of  `BETWEEN` and `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT
SUM(DISTINCT `table2`.`ratio` BETWEEN 0.00 AND 0.25) `count`
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.user =table2.user) GROUP BY table1.user

SELECT
SUM(DISTINCT `table2`.`ratio` BETWEEN 0.25 AND 0.50) `count`
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.user =table2.user) GROUP BY table1.user

SELECT
SUM(DISTINCT `table2`.`ratio` BETWEEN 0.50 AND 0.75 ) `count`
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.user =table2.user) GROUP BY table1.user

SELECT
SUM(DISTINCT `table2`.`ratio` BETWEEN 0.75 AND 0.99) `count`
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.user =table2.user) GROUP BY table1.user
```

Or you can just combine them one as

```
SELECT  '0.00 - 0.25' Ratio_Group ,
SUM(DISTINCT `table2`.`ratio` BETWEEN 0.00 AND 0.25) `count`
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.user =table2.user) GROUP BY table1.user
UNION ALL
SELECT '0.25 - 0.50' Ratio_Group ,
SUM(DISTINCT `table2`.`ratio` BETWEEN 0.25 AND 0.50) `count`
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.user =table2.user) GROUP BY table1.user
UNION ALL
SELECT '0.50 - 0.75' Ratio_Group ,
SUM(DISTINCT `table2`.`ratio` BETWEEN 0.50 AND 0.75 ) `count`
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.user =table2.user) GROUP BY table1.user
UNION ALL
SELECT '0.75 - 0.99' Ratio_Group ,
SUM(DISTINCT `table2`.`ratio` BETWEEN 0.75 AND 0.99) `count`
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.user =table2.user) GROUP BY table1.user
```

**EDIT** Below query will count the distinct users for each ratio group

```
SELECT  '0.00 - 0.25' Ratio_Group ,
COUNT(DISTINCT `table2`.`user` ) `count`
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.user =table2.user) 
WHERE `table2`.`ratio` BETWEEN 0.00 AND 0.25

UNION ALL

SELECT '0.25 - 0.50' Ratio_Group ,
COUNT(DISTINCT `table2`.`user`) `count`
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.user =table2.user) 
WHERE  `table2`.`ratio` BETWEEN 0.25 AND 0.50

UNION ALL

SELECT '0.50 - 0.75' Ratio_Group ,
COUNT(DISTINCT `table2`.`user` ) `count`
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.user =table2.user) 
WHERE `table2`.`ratio` BETWEEN 0.50 AND 0.75
UNION ALL

SELECT '0.75 - 0.99' Ratio_Group ,
COUNT(DISTINCT `table2`.`user`) `count`
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.user =table2.user) 
WHERE `table2`.`ratio` BETWEEN 0.75 AND 0.99
```

### [**See Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a8bb/1)

Comment: This almost works, but the query returns several rows in the 'count' field. I need 1 row returned for each ratio group.

Comment: I am looking more for a solution like this (4 separate queries - 1 for each rang). The solution above returns each user as a row and if that user falls within the specified range they are '1' and if not '0'. If there are 20 users in table 1 I get 20 results when I should only get 1 result with the total for each range. I tried adding another SUM() in front of the SUM() thinking it would just add up all the 1's but it gave an error.

Comment: @user1885697 See my updated answer and also [***see fiddle demo here***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a8bb/1)

Comment: The edit works great. I can just use each query without the UNION ALL and it will work for each ratio group I need. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind only grabbing the groups that have members, you can do something like this. It uses an inner query to grab unique members and their corresponding ratios, then uses a containing table to group them into ratio groups by those ratios. The nice thing is you don't hard code row groups, which isn't very SQL-like; the downside is you don't see row "members" that have a count of 0.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        ((CEIL(ratio * 4) * 0.25 ) - 0.25),
        " - ",
        (CEIL( ratio *4 ) * 0.25)
    ) AS ratio_group,
    COUNT(user) AS user_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        t1.user,
        t2.ratio
    FROM
        `table1` t1
    INNER JOIN
        `table2` t2 ON t2.user = t1.user
    GROUP BY
        t1.user
) virtual_table
GROUP BY
    CEIL(ratio * 4)
```

Per your additional comments, you can combine all the data into a string, and assign to a variable like so. This is a hell of a bastardization. What you do with that data (it's essentially a CSV string at that point) is up to YOU, haha.

```
@data = 
(SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(combined SEPARATOR ';')
FROM (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            '"',
            CONCAT(
                ((CEIL(ratio * 4) * 0.25) - 0.25),
                " - ",
                (CEIL( ratio *4 ) * 0.25)
            ),
            '",',
            COUNT( user )
        ) AS combined
    FROM (
        SELECT
            t1.user,
            t2.ratio
        FROM 
            `table1` t1
        INNER JOIN
            `table2` t2 ON t2.user = t1.user
        GROUP BY
            t1.user
    ) virtual_table
    GROUP BY
        CEIL( ratio *4 )
) virtual_table2 )
```

Comment: This seems to work well, but how do I modify so that each ratio field is returned separately? I need to assign each sum value to a variable in a stored proc.

Comment: Unless there is a way to assign each row to a variable?

Comment: The 2nd query I gave you will give you a single cell result like so: `"0.00 - 0.25",1;"0.25 - 0.50",1;"0.75 - 1.00",2`

Comment: Ok, I feel a bit stupid, but each group should be assigned to a single variable, or how do I select 1 of the 4 prices of data in the @data to be used in a formula? The formula calls for each of the variables to be used in a different part of the formula. Ultimately I need something like '@range1'; '@range2'; '@range3'; and '@range4' to represent each quartile.